# Access related data from two databases through a single EF 6 data layer

Tags: entity-framework-6

My team would like to separate User data from our core application data.  We're using SQL Server 2014 and EF 6.x Code First.  If we create a Users database and an Application database is there any way to tell EF about a relationship between the User object and and Order object? Assuming the Orders are stored in the application database and the users are stored in the Users database.  We know that we could instantiate the User from the Users database and then query the Application database for a list of orders, but what we're looking for is a solution that functions as if the tables were both in the same database, such as when a User is retrieved its list of Orders is available without a second call.

Basically, we're looking for a way to map entities to a specific context and then instantiate each context pointing to its respective database and let EF sort out the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to do some configuration one the database servers.

Your Application database can define a Synonym to the table in the Users database, which you can then map an entity to as if it were a normal table in the Application DB.

As far as Entity Framework is concerned, it uses the same DbContext pointing to your Application database, but it can pull information from your Users database.

One downside with this is that your Application database needs to be setup to point at a specific Users database.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, this sounds like it will do exactly what we're looking to do!  The downside you mention isn't an issue for us as there will only be a single Users database but possibly multiple application databases (depending on the isolation levels required by our clients).  I'll mark this as the answer once I've taken the idea for a spin.

Comment: @MikeDevenney The issue really shows up when you have multiple environments. If you're not careful, you might accidentally point your QA Application database against your PROD Users database (or something else).

Comment: @MikeDevenney Did that end up solving your issue?

Comment: We're still ironing out the wrinkles, but it seems to be working exactly as we need it to.  Thanks!

Comment: Wrinkles ironed out, it works perfectly.  Since we're using Code First, pointing to the wrong place should be avoidable as all connection strings are set with config transformations.  No human intervention to mess things up.